# Genymotion, Unfortunately your APP has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, genymotion

My problem is very commun here, there are many topics talks about it, i tried everything but it's not working, but i'm sure that it's not hard enough, maybe because my stupidity lol ...

My story start when i converted a **APK File** to **Source Code**, then i imported the source code to **ECLIPSE**, i did some changes like changing the app name..

But when i want to see the changes i did in **Genymotion**, it shows : 
Unfortunatly my app has stopped...

here are the screenshots :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VIkr.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aReZh.jpg

Thanks in Advance Guys :)

Comment: We would need to see the code associated with the line represented in your LogCat. Going to assume that you are new to this and, based on your question, that is gibberish to you so I would recommend learning how to debug from a LogCat stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Bro,

I can do a screenshot of the logcat here..
Do you think that this problem can happen because of the package name changing?

Comment: It is very possible.

Comment: LogCat

http://i.imgur.com/4aloptG.png

Comment: post your code here so we can help you. It is not an issue of genymotion.

Comment: @SuhasB You mean Logcat code?

Comment: @Paypowa Android code and Logcat so we help you in better way.

Comment: Thanks bro, @SuhasB :)
I'm Uploading the files now, 5 minutes max they'll be here :)

Comment: Apk File 

http://www.mediafire.com/download/5fuomsjgjia8bgp/StartActivity.apk

Comment: Source Code :

http://www.mediafire.com/download/pbkxf2jp5qf194q/Mebtoul.rar

Comment: And Finally Logcat

http://www.mediafire.com/download/c7eayjhbbentaz7/Paypowa.txt

Comment: You jacked up your packaging. `Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mebtoul.weightmachineken/com.arabmobily.weightmachine.StartActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.arabmobily.weightmachine.StartActivity"` tells me that you were using com.mebtoul.weightmachineken as your package name and then changed it to com.arabmobily.weightmachine, but somewhere you messed something up.

Comment: so it's just about package name? @zgc7009

Comment: I think so, something in your package got messed up in refactoring it.

Comment: after looking at the Package Name,i still have the same problem, the package is good no Eror showen, only when i run the app with Genymotion...